# Javascript jQuery external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running an index.html file after outsourcing the control.js file it doesnt work together:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="control.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="space"></p>
  <button id="temp1">Sensor1</button>
  <p id="space2"></p>
  <button id="temp2">Sensor2</button>
 <body>
</html>
```

my control.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#temp1").click(function(){
        $.get("/temp", function(data){
            document.getElementById('space').innerHTML = data;
        });
    });
    $("button#temp2").click(function(){
        $.get("/temp2", function(data){
            document.getElementById('space2').innerHTML = data;
        });
    });
});
```

doesn't work together, so what do I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is control.js in the same directory as index.html? And are you actually closing the `script` that is referencing jQuery?

Comment: looks like a file path problem. Did you check browser console for JS errors?

Comment: yes it's in the same dircetory. Im closing it yes, i delete the script which I wrote in the control.js

Comment: Are you using your local file system?

Comment: Im using my local file system, debugger don't show any problem =(

Comment: @user3340823: If we could see the **index.html** file modified with the instruction `<script src="control.js"></script>` in it, it would help for trying to find the bug

Comment: i changed my post with the new index.html file, without reputation of 10 i can't answer my own questions =(

Comment: Try putting an alert or console log in the very beginning of control.js to see if it's actually loaded.

Comment: Code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u7kb7/ Take a look at the developer toolbar of your browser of choice. First network tab: Are both files loaded? Second console tab: Are there JS errors?

Comment: no the problem is that the control.js is not loaded. both files are in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > but it doesn't work, so what do I wrong?

Try putting the script tag before the end of the body (which actually needs to be added "/body")

Comment: okay i changed it, nothing happend. the same problem still exists. i closed the body tag (thanks). Firebug told me: Cannot GET /control.js so what i have to do?

Comment: firefox has a debugging plugin "firebug" that has (among other things) a console that will report errors, and a 'net' tab that records the loading of external js, it might give you more info.....

Comment: are you getting a 404 ('not found')? Its hard to see the big picture at this point. jsFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/] helps SO be efficient at finding problems; maybe to can load the code so contributors can help more quickly...

Comment: no not 404. in firebug: Can not get /outlets.js. I run the index.html with an simple http node.js server, is there any problem to get the control.js? the server file the index file and the control file are all in the same folder

Comment: sounds like a node.js config issue. search SO with the name of the node config file and you might get some clues. Sorry, I don't know node....